Connect any port on vds with domain
I have a vds server on cloud and i buy a domain at same web site. I set DNS  adress to my vds server ip aress. And i tried access my web site running on port 80. But i cant access. I use nginx web server for this. I dont know how to set nginx config file etc. How can i access my web site through my domain.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Post your nginx configuration.

"VDS" or "VPS"? What research have you done regarding configuring Nginx in order to accomplish what you need?

Update your Nginx configuration to include your domain name in the server block, and ensure it listens on port 80. Then reload Nginx to apply the changes.
